# Is my hard drive damaged?

Tags: windows-xp, hard-drive

I think my hard drive is damaged. My hard drives:

SAMSUNG SV4002H 40GB (Windows XP) - I found this drive in a old broken computer (this is the broken one, well I think)
WDC WD1600JB-00GVA0 160GB (data and other files) - OK

Sometimes while launching [installed Windows for the first time get this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/830084). And Microsoft says that:

```
The hardware where you are trying to install Windows XP may not be compatible with Windows XP.
The hard disk where you are trying to install Windows XP may be damaged.
```

I can only use "Full format" option to format drive, because if I use "Quick" nothing happens, like about 30 minutes the setup still will show only 0%.
Windows runs but with some problems:
CHKDSK fails to check drive (freezes) but the second drive OK.
Some applications like "Opera" crashes on that disk.
Can't open "Control panel" - explorer.exe crashes.
Can't open "Display properties" - RunDLL.exe crashes.
Some updates can't be installed.

**UPDATE**

While writing this Question I copied "Opera" from second disk to damaged one and EVERYTHING worked - "Control panel" etc. Why and how? I don't believe it! What's going on! C'mon, now updates are working fully and correctly.

**UPDATE 2**
Because I haven't any CDs I can't burn UBCD, but there is "IDE DPS Self-test" in BIOS. After 20 seconds of testing it fails:
[image: TEST]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally if a program made by manufacturer claims the drive is dead, it's usually best to replace it right away. Copy any data you can, don't use it for anything else, replace.

The Ultimate Boot CD can also be installed on USB stick. See here: http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/customize.html#usb

Comment: I dont have any data on this drive because i know its broken. All important data is on my second drive, i spend 5 hours to copy data to flash and internet storages, i will use my second drive for windows. this broken HDD i will DESTROY!

Comment: I dont have any USB sticks left, all with copied data :D

Answer (score 1):

Download [UBCD](http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/), (or just HDAT on it's own - http://www.hdat2.com/).

For UBCD, go to `Hard Disk Tools` > `Diagnostic Tools` and run `HDAT 2"

Choose the drive and do a scan.

This is a very good tool that should give a better indication of the state of your hard drive.

Signs are not good from what you have said, but, this should confirm it for you.